# How do I understand how to refactor code in to functions for future use

Tags: python, arrays, function, refactoring

I am taking a class using Python Crash Course Text. The class was supposed to be in person but has moved to online. I am confused with the following assignment and would like to know if someone can help walk me through it.

Refactoring your code is the process of converting sections of your code into functions that can be reused again in other parts of your code.

In a previous assignment, More Fun with Test Grades, you were supposed to identify if anyone scored a 100. You are going to take the section of your code that identifies if anyone scored a 100 and convert it to a function called has_100() (5 points). Think about what parameter(s) your function may need and what data type your function needs to return. The has_100() function does not need to print any information. It only needs to look at a list of grades and return True or False depending on if the list contains 100 or not.

You also need to create a function called print_top_grades(). In order to make this function reusable, it should have a couple of parameters; (1) the number of grades to print and (2) the list containing the grades. This will be different from the has_100() function because print_top_grades() won't return anything. It simply uses a for loop to print the top n grades in the list in descending order. Note: since lists are mutable, you have to be careful not to permanently sort the list. You only want to print the top n grades.

Be sure to account for an empty list.
If the number of grades to print is larger than the number of grades in the list, all grades should be printed in descending order. For example, if there are 3 grades in the list but someone tries to print the top 5, only 3 grades should print.

```
#more fun with test grades assignment
# Do not modify: required for assignment
import random
last_score = random.randint(99,100)
if bool(random.getrandbits(1)):
    grades = [71, 64, 82, 72, 56, 99, 96, 99, 86, 84, 90, last_score]
else:
    grades = []
# Do not modify: required for assignment
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment is simple, instead of writing the whole logic without using functions (as it is written now) you need to separate the code into functions.

should be something like this:

```
def has_100():
    """Identifies if anyone scored a 100"""
    # your code here

def print_top_grades():
    """print the top n grades in the list in descending order"""
    # your code here

def main():
    """Here you will write the execution of the program
    reusing the functions above according to the task assigned"""
    # your code here

# This is used to execute our file when you call 'python file.py' in your 
# terminal
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Add the parameters you need to the functions (but not to the main()) to fulfil the task of each one.

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful and I was able to solve the question. Is it okay to delete the question so I does not give the code (part of the assignment) away to other students?

Comment: Maybe your question can help other students that have the same doubts in the future, but it's up to you if you want to delete the question. Whether you will delete it or not, do not forget to give an upvote to the answer. :D

Comment: I removed the code that was not needed to answer this portion of the question. Thank you for your help!!!!